# MonthCalendar datechanged event

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a project to save patients appointments for specific dates.My project owns a datagridview linked with a sqlserver database.The grid contains a column named "Time".I assigned values of this column in sqlserver.When i enter the form datagridview contains 10 empty rows so the user can save the patients in specific times.The form contains also a monthcalendar.What i want is to show my grid with empty rows for each monthcalendar date,to save the appointments in different dates.

I saw this below but he used dataset and im working with entity model i dont know how to realize it, please help me.

```
Public Function connect()

    Dim sql As String = "Data Source=RINOR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ordinanca;Integrated Security=True"
    Return New Sqlconnection(sql)
End Function

Public Function search(pmtData As Date) As DataTable

    Using con As SqlConnection = connect()

        Dim dt As Datatable = New Datatable()
        Try

            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE DT='" + pmtData + "'"
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New sqlCommand(query, con)
            Dim da As SqldataAdapter = New sqlDataadapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)

        Catch ex As Exception

            Messagebox.show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.close()
        End Try

        Return dt

    End Using
End Function

Private Sub monthcalendar1_datechanged(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles monthcalendar1.datechanged

    Dim datatable As datatable
    Dim pmtdata As Date
    pmtdata = monthcalendar1.selectionstart
    datatable = search(pmtdata)
    gridview.datasource = datatable

End Sub
```

My code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim db As New OrdinancaEntities
  Dim pacienti As New Pacientet
  Dim isEditing As Boolean = True
  Dim selectedPacient As Int16

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BindingDatagridView()
    FillData("")
  End Sub

  Sub BindingDatagridView()
    dgvPacientet.DataSource = db.Pacientets.ToList()
  End Sub

  Sub FillData(searchText As String)
    Dim data As List(Of Pacientet)
    Dim context As New OrdinancaEntities
    If searchText = "" Then
        data = context.Pacientets.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Id).ToList()
    Else
        data = context.Pacientets.Where(Function(t) t.Emri.StartsWith(searchText) Or t.Mbiemri.StartsWith(searchText)).OrderBy(Function(t) t.Id).ToList()
    End If
    dgvPacientet.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgvPacientet.DataSource = data
    SelectClient()
  End Sub

  Sub EnableButton(bPërditëso As Boolean)
    btnPërditëso.Enabled = bPërditëso
  End Sub

  Sub SelectClient()
    If dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        selectedPacient = CInt(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Id").Value.ToString())

        txtEmri.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Emri").Value.ToString()
        txtMbiemri.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Mbiemri").Value.ToString()

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Emri_prindit").Value) Then
            txtEmri_prindit.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Emri_prindit").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtEmri_prindit.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Datelindja").Value) Then
            txtDatelindja.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Datelindja").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtDatelindja.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Numri_telefonit").Value) Then
            txtNumri.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Numri_telefonit").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtNumri.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Diagnoza").Value) Then
            txtDiagnoza.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Diagnoza").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtDiagnoza.Text = ""
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Tretmani_planifikuar").Value) Then
            txtTretmani_planifikuar.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Tretmani_planifikuar").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtTretmani_planifikuar.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Tretmani_kryer").Value) Then
            txtTretmani_kryer.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Tretmani_kryer").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtTretmani_kryer.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Pagesa").Value) Then
            txtPagesa.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Pagesa").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtPagesa.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Pagoi").Value) Then
            txtPagoi.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Pagoi").Value.ToString()
        Else
            txtPagoi.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Doktori").Value) Then
            cboDoktori.Text = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Doktori").Value.ToString()
        Else
            cboDoktori.Text = ""
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Dt_terminit").Value) Then
            Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart = dgvPacientet.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells("Dt_terminit").Value.ToString()
        Else
            Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart = Date.Now
        End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnPërditëso_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPërditëso.Click

    If isEditing Then
        Dim context As New OrdinancaEntities
        Dim client As Pacientet = (From c In context.Pacientets
                               Where c.Id = selectedPacient
                                  Select c).FirstOrDefault()
        client.Emri = txtEmri.Text
        client.Mbiemri = txtMbiemri.Text
        client.Emri_prindit = txtEmri_prindit.Text
        client.Datelindja = txtDatelindja.Text
        client.Numri_telefonit = txtNumri.Text
        client.Diagnoza = txtDiagnoza.Text
        client.Tretmani_planifikuar = txtTretmani_planifikuar.Text
        client.Tretmani_kryer = txtTretmani_kryer.Text
        client.Pagesa = txtPagesa.Text
        client.Pagoi = txtPagoi.Text
        client.Doktori = cboDoktori.SelectedItem
        client.Dt_terminit = Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart
        context.SaveChanges()
        BindingDatagridView()
    End If
    isEditing = True
    FillData("")
    MessageBox.Show("Të dhënat u insertuan me sukses.")
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    ClearText()
  End Sub

  Sub ClearText()
    txtEmri.Clear()
    txtMbiemri.Clear()
    txtNumri.Clear()
    txtDiagnoza.Clear()
    txtPagesa.Clear()
    txtPagoi.Clear()
    cboDoktori.Text = "Zgjedh doktorin"
    txtEmri.Focus()
    txtTretmani_planifikuar.Clear()
    txtTretmani_kryer.Clear()
    txtDatelindja.Clear()
    txtEmri_prindit.Clear()
  End Sub

  Private Sub txtKerko_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtKerko.TextChanged
    FillData(txtKerko.Text)
  End Sub

  Private Sub dgvPacientet_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvPacientet.RowEnter
    SelectClient()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: replace the datatable that's returned from "Search" with your entity list? As long as the property names of your entity match the gridview it should work?

Comment: @Adyson 
i can't use sqlcommand,sqlconnection,dataAdapter while im using Entity model

Comment: exactly, that's what I'm saying. Replace all the code in the search function with the code you use to retrieve your entity. From your question it sounds like you wrote that already. You can still use a list of your entities to bind to the gridview.

Comment: Could you please be more specific and write some code to understand you , thanks a lot preliminarily

Comment: well, you have got your code to get the entity, right? Edit the question to show me that code and we shoud be able to combine it with this other code

Comment: i edited you can see the code

Comment: you missed some of the formatting! but thanks I will take a look soon when I have time, probably tomorrow

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Dim db As New OrdinancaEntities
    Dim pacienti As New Pacientet
    Dim isEditing As Boolean = True
    Dim selectedPacient As Int16

This is what i have in the public class because i posted it not correctly, ok i will appreciate your help because my client is wating for me , have nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something like what you need. It simply replaces all the DataTable-related functionality inside the "search" function with a much simpler call to your Entity Framework class:

```
Private Sub monthcalendar1_datechanged(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles monthcalendar1.datechanged
  Dim pmtdata As Date
  pmtdata = monthcalendar1.selectionstart
  Dim records = db.Pacientets.Where(Function(p)  p.dt_terminit.Equals(pmtdata)).ToList()

  'add extra rows if not all rows populated
  If (records.Count() < 10) Then
    Dim timeSlots = db.TimeSlots 'get the list of all possible appointment times in one day, this is a new table you must create and populate in advance

    For Each(slot in timeSlots)
      'here, check that the slots's time is not in any of the items in the "records" list
      'if it's not, add it to the Pacientes table with only time and date completed.
    Next

    'requery the DB
    records = db.Pacientets.Where(Function(p)  p.dt_terminit.Equals(pmtdata)).ToList()
  End If

  gridview.datasource = records
End Sub
```

Obviously you'll have to change any variable or field names, such as the monthcalendar or gridview, to whatever you are using. I've used `Time.Date` as well, on the basis that your Time column will contain specific times, whereas the month calendar contains dates with no times.

Also, I don't know if "Pacientets" is the correct entitity to query here. I don't speak your language but it sounds like a list of patients. If you're giving times, presumably you have another entity which describes a list of appointments which relate to a specific time, and a specific patient?

Comment: hi , i tried your answer but as i mentioned when i enter the form the datagridview contains 10 rows with empty strings.I filled these rows in sqlserver i let them empty except Time, in the column time i inserten hours from 09:00 to 18:00 , so when i enter the form i select a row which contains a specific time , write patient informations in text Boxes and then click button Perditeso which means update in your language and then the patient is inserted in that specific time.

Comment: With your code the gridview is without rows , i need those rows that i created in sql every time i enter the form cause with those rows i specify in which time i have to insert the patient. Have a nice day ! Hoping for your answer

Comment: so...you created the 10 rows in SQL and yet they are not returned? Which table in the database are those rows in? Are they in Pacientets, or another table? And does your "Time" column also contain a date as well as a time of day?

Comment: The rows are created in Sql and when i click update those rows are shown but when i try to select a row it turns to an error . Rows are created in table Pacientet in Sql table name is Pacientet ,and the time Column contains only time of day

Comment: "the time Column contains only time of day". Well in that case how do you expect it to relate to a date? In the original question you implied this time column was sufficient to match time _and_ date. Do you have another column containing the date, which the query I wrote can compare to? Otherwise, how do you know exactly when the appointment takes place?

Comment: Yes i have column dt_terminit which contains only date and this column has the value of the selected date in month calendar

Comment: right so I have changed the query so that the selected date in the month calendar is matched against the column dt_terminit in the database. That should give you any rows in the database which are on the same day as the currently selected calendar date.

Comment: you can edit the question to include images (or links to images on imgur or somesuch) very easily, no need to email them. And then everyone who reads the question in future can benefit. What is the data type of "dt_terminit" column? It needs to be a Date or DateTime column. If it's a varchar or something, then change it to a date. Also, is the column nullable? That could be the cause of the error.

Comment: I cant include images because of my reputation , im new member. The data type of dt_terminit is only date it is ok , grid now is showing rows of the selected date but not showing 10 rows , i dont need just to search patients of selected date i need to insert them on those 10 rows

Comment: sounds like you need to pre-populate your DB with the rows in advance, containing only the dates/times? Or, you have a separate table, with all the possible times for a single day. Then, when the date changes, you query the DB for any existing patient records. Compare them against the possible times. If there are times that are not used, add the rows to the patient table, and then query again, and bind the gridview to the second query result.

Comment: I will explain you in these steps.

First i open the application , it shows me a datagrid containing 10 rows empty rows with columns of patient informations.
Monthcalendar date is today.
From those 10 rows i select example row 6 in that row Column Time has value 12:00 which means that the patient wants to set the appointment on 12:00 then i write informations in text box , click button Perditeso-Update and then the patient is inserted in row 6 , when i click another date not today , i want the grid with 10 rows without the patient that i already inserted because he appointed another date

Comment: what I described in my last comment will give you that. Also it will not create empty rows for times where there is already a patient booked, instead it will show you the existing booking.

Comment: that's excactly what i want but i dont know which is the correct code to realize this

Comment: don't have time to cover all of it now but have updated with more of a hint. See if you understand now. There is just one bit of code instead the loop remaining to write.